# discord.js Stop that the Bot is turing off after an Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hey everytime i get an Error the Bot turns off... And i dont want that. Can i somewhere turn it off or something like this?

I tried something like

```
client.on("error", () => { client.login(config.token) })
```

But thats not working. Some of the Errors are:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

D:\Discord Bot\Space Network\spacenetwork\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\ChannelCreate.js:9
    const existing = client.channels.cache.has(data.id);
    at ChannelCreateAction.handle (D:\Discord Bot\Space Network\spacenetwork\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\ChannelCreate.js:9:53)
    at User.createDM (D:\Discord Bot\Space Network\spacenetwork\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\User.js:257:46)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async D:\Discord Bot\Space Network\spacenetwork\index.js:663:22

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null
```

Comment: `<Client>.on('error' ...)` only works for client based errors, not JavaScript. Fixing any bugs with your actual code should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your code has errors in it, the best practice is to fix the error instead of bypassing it `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null` this means, whatever that comes before 'id' property is null

`const existing = client.channels.cache.has(data.id);` the error is at this line, try logging `data.id`, according to the error 'data' is null, fix that and it should solve the problem

The point to note is, reading the errors, finding the source of the error and fixing the error :)

Comment: I was doing that but it dosnt work. "The point to note is, reading the errors, finding the source of the error and fixing the error :)"

Comment: do console.log(data); and check what it shows

Comment: Nothing its just:
```const existing = client.channels.cache.has(data.id);
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at ChannelCreateAction.handle (D:\Discord Bot\Space Network\spacenetwork\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\ChannelCreate.js:9:53)
    at User.createDM (D:\Discord Bot\Space Network\spacenetwork\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\User.js:257:46)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)```

Comment: @DuBistMutig add this code console.log(data); then run the file, the error says that data does not exist, you need to fix that

Comment: The output is just: null

Comment: @DuBistMutigi meant what is data, where did you import it from

Comment: ChannelCreate or what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodemon. I think they make it so that whenever you make changes to your code and save it, it automatically runs, and if it crashes, it restarts it automatically. However, I’d be careful with this, considering if have the error in the ready message, the bot will connect over and over again, and I think discord will automatically shut it down.
`npm install nodemon -g`